# Empty Model#changes when creating record with factory_bot in rspec after updating rails from 5.0.7 to 5.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

As stated in title of the topic I faced with issues after updating rails from 5.0.7 to 5.2.8.

Also was updated:

- factory_bot_rails from 4.11.1 to 6.2.0
- rspec-rails from 4.0.1 to 5.1.2
- rspec from 3.9.0 to 3.11.0

There are many failed tests(most of them about some deprecations) but some of them is tied with strange behaviour when creating model records via FactoryBot.

When I use old RoR and old gems, the `ModelName#changes` returns values correctly. I mean it returns changes after `create(:model_name)` calling. But after updating rails and another gems `ModelName#changes` just returns empty hash. Therefore a lots of specs failed.

Also I noticed it stopped create necessary records that should be created via callbacks.

For example `create(:application)` has additional `after(:create)` with `application.save!` statement and it should call some callback at `Application` which creates `AnotherModel` record. But it doesnt happen anymore after rails & gems update.

I can't figire out what exactly changed in rails or another gems what caused such consequences?

Any advices are appreciated!

Before updates:

[image: before rails update]

After updates:

[image: after rails update]

#### Update #1

I looked at `ActiveModel::Dirty` module and found it was changed:

```
# Old implementation Rails 5.0.7
    def changed_attributes
      @changed_attributes ||= ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
    end
```

```
# New implementation Rails 5.2.8
    def changed_attributes
      # This should only be set by methods which will call changed_attributes
      # multiple times when it is known that the computed value cannot change.
      if defined?(@cached_changed_attributes)
        @cached_changed_attributes
      else
        attributes_changed_by_setter.reverse_merge(mutations_from_database.changed_values).freeze
      end
    end
```

It seems that's my case(

Answer (score 0):

I've figure out I should first update to Rails 5.1 from 5.0, fix all deprecations etc, and then update to Rails 5.2.

It turns out Rails v5.1 have a lot deprecations about `ActiveModel::Dirty`'s attribute changes methods, where it states that I have to use new methods instead old which will be deprecated in Rails 5.2 version.

That's why my code was broken and specs was failed.

https://www.rubyinrails.com/2019/04/08/rails-changed-behavior-of-attribute-changed-in-callbacks/